# Apache2 won't run: error message-system/not/booted/(PID1)= error messaged shortened

Tags: server, apache2, windows-subsystem-for-linux, kali-linux-tools

I tried running `apt-get install apache2`, and I'm up to date. I ran the different variations of `sudo sytemctl enable --apache2.service` and I get the message:

```
System has not been booted with system as init system (PID1).
Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

Any help with this issue?

I tried the `wsl --terminate`, and it did not work either.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  I believe that my answer on the linked duplicate should answer your question, but if for some reason it doesn't, please let me know so that I can look at reopening this one. Thanks!

Comment: It most certainly did, thank you very much. I checked the few that popped up and did not see your advice, so I apologize, but apache2 is up and running.

Comment: No worries at all!  Duplicates are often hard to search.  Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

In earlier versions of Linux distributions, the `init` command was used as the default init system, which was responsible for starting system services, mounting filesystems, and managing system resources. However, most modern Linux distributions now use `systemd` as the default init system.

As it is clearly written in the error message that "System has not been booted with system as init system" and you are using `wsl` which uses `init` so instead of using `systemctl` which Is for newer versions of Linux, use `service` command.

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

---

to see which is used to start the system `(init|systemd)` you can use `cat /proc/1/comm` to see the name of PID `1`

it will look something like this for `init`

[image: system started with init]

and like this for `systemd`

[image: system started with systemd]